# IE9 plug-in to quickly update bookmarks

Tags: plugins, bookmarks, internet-explorer-9

I have bookmarks that refer to what page I'm up to on a web site, rather than the web site itself, such as blogs that have five years worth of pages I want to catch up on.  When I finish reading, I copy the URL, open the bookmark's properties, and paste the URL so I can return to this page next time.  I want to simplify this.

My first thought is a plug-in that lets me right-click a bookmark and select *Update to current page*.  Is there a plug-in for IE9 that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote you an AutoHotkey script to effortlessly update your bookmark URLs.

### Script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, Regex

#IfWinActive, Internet Explorer
#LButton:: ;Win+LeftClick

originalClipboard := Clipboard

Clipboard = ;empty clipboard

Send, ^l ;Select address bar
Send, ^c ;copy
ClipWait ;wait for clipboard

Click Right
Send, p ;Properties

WinWaitActive, Properties
Send, ^v ;paste
Send, {Enter}

Clipboard := originalClipboard

#IfWinActive    
return
```

### Instructions:

Hold down the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and **Click** on the bookmark you want to update. You will see the Properties window flash as the URL is updated from the address bar. :)

---

**Download:** [http://ahk.igalvez.net/IEUpdateBookmark.exe, 784 KB](http://ahk.igalvez.net/IEUpdateBookmark.exe)

Comment: Beautiful!  Thanks for that!  I'll have to look into AutoHotkey.